# rush setup angular monorepo with libs

Tags: angular, monorepo, rush

I try to setup a monorepo with rush and angular workspaces and libs.

But I struggle to make it work.

Normally you have a workspace with multiple libs and build the libs from the workspace with `ng build <libname>`. But in rush I must specify a project root and a build command in the package.json in each project root. So I can‘t have multiple build commands for one project root. Or am I wrong?

I have tried to create one workspace per lib but since the real package name is in the libs package.json and and in the workspace package.json. It also doesn’t work.

Currently I use nx but I am not satisfied with it for various reasons so I want to switch.

Anyone has setup and rush repo with multiple workspaces and libs with an angular project?

Answer (score -3):

Your question is not very clear for me.

If you followed Nx guidelines properly to create the monorepo, you no need to worry. Nx provides an option to build how many apps you want.

Refer: https://nx.dev/latest/angular/cli/build

Comment: In short my question is how to setup a rush monorepo with multiple angular libs which are all defined in the rush projects so the build cache is used properly. Hope this is better understandable :)